# How to disable a row by selecting value from comboBox in datagridview?

Tags: c#, gridview

[image]

Here I have a column name "Status" in which I am using `ComboBox` whose values are "Pending" and "Delivered" now I want that when a user selects the delivered from the ComboBox then the entire row or this control should be disabled so user could not change it again and by default its value should be "Pending" how can i do it? Is it possible to disable a single row in gridview?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable an individual row.  However you can make it readonly:

`DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;`

(This makes row with index of rowIndex set to readonly).

For your specific example, you would want to handle the CellValueChanged event of the datagridview and have code along the lines of:

```
        void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 4 && DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "Delivered")
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: when m trying with this code on form load it gives me exception that " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." at Rows[e.RowIndex] so wats going wrong should I have to intialize the RowIndex too.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the RowChanged event and do something like

```
if (Status == 'Delivered')
{
   e.Row.Enabled = False;
}
```